# Access violation reading from location in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

Why is the last statement throwing Access Violation?

I wanted to write the status of a service into an XML file.

```
#define STR_SERVICE_STATUS_INPUT__XML_CONTENT  _T("<SERVICE NAME = \"%s\" STARTUP_TYPE = \"0x%d\" />\r\n\r\n")

CString         csWriteBufferTemp;

DWORD           dwBufferSize;

DWORD           dwBytesNeeded;

SC_HANDLE       schHandle;


LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG      st_lpqscServiceInfo;

schHandle  = OpenService(IN_schHandle, (CString)cArgentServices[i], SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);

bRC = QueryServiceConfig(schHandle, NULL, 0, &dwBytesNeeded);

dwBufferSize        = dwBytesNeeded;    //Size needed.

st_lpqscServiceInfo = (LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, dwBufferSize);

bRC = QueryServiceConfig(schHandle, st_lpqscServiceInfo, dwBufferSize, &dwBytesNeeded);
    csWriteBufferTemp.Format(STR_SERVICE_STATUS_INPUT__XML_CONTENT__,st_lpqscServiceInfo->lpDisplayName,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your replies and suggestions, I found the answer on another site. I don't know if this is the correct way but it works!

```
LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG
            st_lpqscServiceInfo;
SC_HANDLE       schHandle;

st_lpqscServiceInfo = (LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 4096);

schHandle   = OpenSCManager(IN_pszMachineName,SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);

bRC = QueryServiceConfig(schHandle, st_lpqscServiceInfo, dwBufferSize, &dwBytesNeeded);

csWriteBufferTemp.Format(STR_SERVICE_STATUS_INPUT__XML_CONTENT__,st_lpqscServiceInfo->lpDisplayName,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly using the wrong string format parameter in `_T("<SERVICE NAME = \"%S\" STARTUP_TYPE = \"0x%d\" />\r\n\r\n")`. The lpServiceStartName member of SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG and CString are both TCHAR-based so they should have matching character types regardless of whether your compiling in Unicode mode or not. In that case, you should be using %s instead of %S.

Comment: Thank-you @TheUndeadFish for the reply, but still doesn't solve my problem.I edited the question as you suggested.

Comment: @sidx There's not too many possibilities if Format is crashing. Have you verified that st_lpqscServiceInfo is being allocated and to the correct size? And that the second QueryServiceConfig call is actually succeeding? Something being wrong with st_lpqscServiceInfo->lpDisplayName is about the only reasonable guess given your code now.

Comment: In my actual code I'm checking all the `schHandle` values to see if the call is succeeding. They're never `NULL`. Also I check the `bRC`s too.

Comment: @sidx Well, I'm not seeing any other issues in the code you've posted. Perhaps there is some difference with your actual code that is related to the problem. Have you tried stepping in with Visual Studio's debugger to see what's going on when the problem occurs? Otherwise, if you can't do that for some reason, then can you create a small self-contained example that reproduces the same problem?

Comment: This piece of code troubled me for a long time and finally I had to allocate the size of `LPQUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG` statically as shown in the answer below. Somehow this works and the other doesn't.